# Type com.google.protobuf.Any$1 is defined multiple times

Tags: android, realm, protocol-buffers

I am implementing protobuf in this way:

```
 implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0'
```

In addition to that, I have realm:

```
 kapt 'io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:6.1.0'
```

When I try to build the code, I get the following error:

```
Type com.google.protobuf.Any$1 is defined multiple times: ..\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\27abd4bf864632f274bb28f15772efb2\jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar:com/google/protobuf/Any$1.class, ..\app\build\intermediates\transforms\RealmTransformer\demo\debug\0\com\google\protobuf\Any$1.class
```

I need to use :

```
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0'
```

since my proto files contain Any.proto

Is there a way to exclude proto files from realm or use the realm Any files in my proto files?

Answer (score -1):

Remove:
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0'

By removing that line, you should get an other error because Duration.proto is not in the package. This bug will be fixed in next version of Protobuf.

There is a work around to fix that:

- Download the jar file of the java version of protobuf
- Download the jar file of the java lite version
- Extract Duration.proto from the java version
- Include Duration.proto into the java lite version
- Copy the jar file of the java lite into your app/libs
- Replace the line in gradle:

  implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'

by

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['protobuf-javalite-3.10.0.jar'])
```

Use the same version of the both jar file.

It's a temporary fix until a new version of protobuf is release.